# iOS - force keyboard to be presented in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

My question is that I have created the view by CGAffineTransform in landscape mode. In my app I have shown each view in portrait mode. But as I told you I have created one view by CGAffineTransform in landscape, because I have to show a spreadsheet on that view in landscape mode. But I did it logically and the keyboard is not showing in landscape mode. Please give me the code to show the keyboard in landscape mode.

Comment: Improve English to get even more answers.

Comment: maybe is better to create a uiviewcontroll instead of a uiview rotated

Comment: Please any one tell me is possible or not ..if it is possible then please give me idea about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this for view in question:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

and this in viewDidLoad

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

I know this sounds odd, but it does work.

Comment: I wonder why the keyboard's behavior is tied to the status bar. Quantum mechanics? :)