# Create Apple TV Apps in portrait orientation mode

Tags: swift, tvos, portrait

For my business purpose we have to place Apple TV in portrait mode. How can I create an app that have portrait orientation?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept from an SDK perspective does not exist. None of the rotation-related methods from iOS made it over to tvOS, and for a good reason. With that said, there is still a small segment where it could be useful to have your tvOS application being rendered with more vertical than horizontal space.
You can read this [post](https://medium.com/itch-design-no/how-to-rotate-tvos-into-portrait-mode-deff37cd56c8) for some help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I followed the post but I  don't have an idea about how to manage keyboard of UITextfield. Even my UITextField is in Vertical orientation my keyboard is not rotating. If I rotate the window then it is not fit in the screen. Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Hi! I do not know what is the reason for this. I tried to answer the question that you asked :)

Comment: As per requirement they place the Apple TV in portrait mode. So that I have to make portrait applications. Did you find out a way to manage keyboard?. All controls I can manage using window rotation method, but couldn't manage Keyboard.

Comment: @iphoneBees can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157582/ios-force-keyboard-to-be-presented-in-landscape-orientation) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495554/keyboard-issue-in-landscape-orientation-xcode-swift)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, but UIInterfaceOrientation method is not available for tvOS. Have to find out some other tricks.

Comment: Sure. If you come across any solution to manage keyboard please let me know.